# Differential Equation of a First Order High Pass Filter

Tags: high-pass-filter

[image]

[image: picture of the circuit]

I am just stumped right now b/c I do not know how to write the "differential equation that describes this system. I did learn to write equations with impedances but I believe this is not what this question is asking for.

I tried writing a KVL around the loop and obtained:

**note: U stands for voltage(my prof likes this notation as opposed to 'V')**

\$ -U_{in} + U_c + U_R  = 0\$

\$ U_{in} = U_R + U_c\$

\$ U_{in} = RC\cdot \frac{dU_o}{dt}\:+\:U_R\$

Let \$U_{in}\$ = \$x\$

and

\$y\$ = \$U_o\$ or \$U_R\$ (same thing)

combining the \$R*C\$ to \$\tau\$ then I would get something like this:

\$x = \tau \cdot \frac{dy}{dt}+y\$

which would be my differential equation???

I feel like this equation is wrong from the start since I derived the same exact equation for low pass filter. How can both low pass and high pass have same exact differential equation? What am I doing wrong? If you do not mind please provide the correct solution with the laplace transformation as well b.c I have no ideas where to begin with that.

Comment: They don't have the same equation. With filters you're looking at the term in the equation that gives the output voltage you're looking for. In a high pass it's the voltage across the resistor i.e. R × i(t)  and in a low pass it's the voltage across the capacitor wrt time

Comment: For a filter,   the cap. impedance as a function of frequency is \$Zc(f)=\dfrac{1}{2π fC}\$  But for time domain, Ic(t)=CdV/dt which is shared by Ir, so the voltage (Ut) is easy to define.

Comment: The third equation goes too fast. You're substituting Uc by R*C * dUo / dt. You should start with the basic relation for a capacitor, Ic = dUc / dt.

Comment: In response to @Huisman.  Ic = dUc / dt is not  Ic = dUo / dt, this is where the error is.

Comment: It's basically the same differential equation for both LPF and HPF; the only difference is whether you nominate \$U_R\$ or \$U_C\$ as the output signal. If you nominate \$U_C\$, then it makes sense to arrange the circuit diagram so that the capacitor is connected to ground. This is easy, as it's a series circuit.

Comment: You missed a \$U_i\$ in the third equation.

Comment: Same differential equation, different TRANSFER FUNCTIONS.

Answer (score 3):

I think your equations are largely correct. Going around the loop I obtain, \$U_{in }= Q/C + U_o\$ , just as you did. Differentiate this now with respect to t, to convert the charge, Q, to a current (since \$I=dQ/dt\$): \$dU_{in}/dt = I/C + d U_o/dt\$. Now applying Ohm's law to the resistor, we have that \$I = U_o/R\$. Substitute this in the equation and you obtain \$dU_{in}/dt = U_o/(RC) + d U_o/dt\$. I believe this is the differential equation the question refers to.

Now make the Laplace transform, and the derivatives are replaced by factors of "s", so that
\$s x(s) = y(s)/(RC) + s y(s)\$. The question says \$x(s)\$ should be the Laplace transform of the unit step function, which is \$x(s)=1/s\$. After some rearranging, this gives the result \$y(s)=1/(s + 1/RC)\$. Using a table of Laplace transforms you can take this back to the t-domain (it is one of the standard cases), and obtain \$U_o(t)\$.

Does this seem reasonable?

Comment: It might be helpful to mention that i=dQ/dt.

Comment: I've done that now - I guess it is wise to include as many intermediate steps as possible. Do you agree with the final result?

Answer (score 1):

Components such as capacitors and conductors have transient and steady state responses which can be represented mathematically using derivatives. We can use the properties of these components to change our filter characteristics. You can have a LPF and HPF represented by the same component by changing it's position.

LPF - the capacitor smooths the voltage at high frequencies because it cannot discharge fast enough before the next cycle of the waveform comes in:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fjFM1s.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

HPF - the capacitor acts like a DC filter and so the low frequency components are removed.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f9L9e3.png)</sup>

If you do KVL around both of these circuits you will get the same differential equation.

PLEASE NOTE THAT THESE COMPONENT VALUES ARE ARBITRARY.

Answer (score 1):

Below is a derivation of the transfer function of a RC high pass filter using potential divider method and Laplace method.

[image: RC High Pass Filter Transfer Transfer Function derivation.]